# Why there are no new dieties?

Tags: gods

Have gods stopped sexually reproducing?
Why no more sons and daughters of dieties come in circulation?

PS: I don't wish to offend others by using above words.  I am just curious to know why.

Comment: Visit related post: [Are new demigods created?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/are-new-demigods-created)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the curse of Goddess Parvati to deities. This is present in *śiva Mahapurana Kumara Khanda chapter 2*.

> O Gods, particularly wicked, selfish and cause pain to others. O Gods for the accomplishment of the selfish motive, you by the supreme lord Siva, have obstructed my conjugal pleasures, making me barren at the same time. No one can feel comfortable by opposing me. Therefore you will also have to suffer. Thus spoke the daughter of Himalaya enraged, pronounced a curse on Gods. *From Today onwards the wives of devas would remain barren (without children). Such of the Gods who will oppose me shall suffer*.

In addition to this curse to the Devas,  She also cursed Agni.

> O Agni, from today, you shall be the consumer of all (sarva bhakshaka). You will also suffer pain.

This curse was pronounced by Pārvati  after knowing that Agni swallowed the semen of Lord śiva. So the count of the devatas was only 33(not 330 millions) when Gaṇeśa and Kārtikeya were born and it is 33 now also.

Comment: What about santoshi maa and shubh labh.?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel See [this](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/5300/which-hindu-texts-contains-the-story-of-santoshi-mata-and-about-her-other-legend)  question for santoshi mata.  Even ganesha and kartikeya are not among devatas eventhough they are worshipped. 33 devatas are 11 rudras, 12 adityas, 8 vasus,1 indra,1 prajapati.

Comment: Acha ji,, Ganesh agar devta nahi hai,,, to kya hain?? Aur shubh labh kya hain?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel English please?

Comment: If Ganesh, kartikya and Shubh labh were not devta or demigods,, what are they?

Comment: @AnubhavGoel I didn't say they are demigods. I said they don't fall under any category of aforementioned 33 devatas mentioned in the Vedas and Upanishads. Ganesha, Kartikeya are technically devas and worshipped. Ganesha means the leader of Ganas and obstacles like a position like Indra. In every cycle, a new ganesha is born in a different way. We worship because he removes obstacles.  Shubh labh are not worshipped like Ganesh, Shiva, Parvati.